# How can I get over all sub-arrays in array?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a main array which has a chance of having sub-array in it (and this array has a chance of having sub-array in it).

This is a part of my code:

```
for i in "${TOTALCOUNT[@]}"
 do
       for g in "${i[@]}" 
       do
               TOECHO=$((TOECHO+g))
       done
 done
 echo "SUM $TOECHO"
```

I think it works for a range of 1 sub-array. But if `TOTALCOUNT` has 2 sub-arrays and they have 1 sub-array and this one has 1 sub-array (actually - it can be almost infinite).

I think you got my point - but unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Arrays in `bash` basically _dissolve_ into one another. There is no way to get back the original array after adding to a parent array

Comment: This is more of an XY problem ( something wrong with your attempt for an unknown problem, rather than explaining an actual problem )

Comment: `has a chance of having sub-array` - can you show example declaration of such an array? How do you store "sub-arrays" inside the first array? `I think you got my point` - no I did not. How do you define "array having an array"? What does it mean? Bash has only 1D arrays and actually only strings, do you store names of other arrays inside the first array?